# PhpStorm generating blocks on initialise

Tags: phpstorm

I wanted to disable the feature of PhpStorm when initialising fields from constructor to make a comment block like this:

```
/**
 * @var ...
 */
```

So I went to `settings > editor > file and code templates > includes`. And from there I deleted the file for generating that block (forgot how it was called), and now when I initialise fields I am getting this

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Which is even more annoying. How can I remove it completely?

Comment: You should have left it empty instead -- that might work better than deleting the file. **P.S.** That entry is called called "PHP Field Doc Comment". **EDIT:** Nope, making it empty does not help either.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATM it's not possible to not to add PHPDoc for such IDE-added fields.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31771 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Answer (score 0):

As of about version 2019.X after removed entry with comment for it, doc block is not longer included for property.